# AFNetworking Empty Request Body

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to make a simple request with the new AFNetworking 2.0 release and I cannot seem to get it to post.  I get a response back from the server "Expecting text/json or application/json body" but according to the documentation on AFNetworking's GitHub page, I'm doing everything as I should be.  It's also worth mentioning that it appears the operation.request.HTTPBody in the last line of my code always appears to be nil.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *request = @{@"email": self.email.text, @"password": self.password.text};
[manager POST:login parameters:request constructingBodyWithBlock:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"DONE!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to log in: %@", operation.responseString);
    NSLog(@"Here's the request: %@", operation.request.HTTPBody);
}];
```

Comment: Have you read about `constructingBodyWithBlock` and what it expects?

Comment: It looks to me it's for file data?

Comment: It's used to create the multi-part formatted `HTTPBody` of the request. You also need to set the serialiser for the request as the default is not JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/Classes/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.html#//api/name/POST%3aparameters%3aconstructingBodyWithBlock%3asuccess%3afailure%3a)

```
POST:parameters:constructingBodyWithBlock:success:failure
```

is for multipart POST requests and its default serialized is not JSON.

> Creates and runs an AFHTTPRequestOperation with a multipart POST request.

You want to use

```
POST:parameters:success:failure:
```

instead, as follows

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *request = @{@"email": self.email.text, @"password": self.password.text};
[manager POST:login parameters:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
  NSLog(@"DONE!");
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to log in: %@", operation.responseString);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)POST:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void ( ^ ) ( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ))failure
```

This method don't require the constructBody block. I don't think the block can be nil.